# opendaylight: genius - application coexistence

Tags: opendaylight

The ODL genius project description aims to allow applications to co-exist. The problem being solved is that all applications share a single table space on the switch and can hence interfere. From the project description page, I see Netvirt has a portion of the table space etc.

I would like to write my application to conform to this architecture to allow for application co-existence rather than have the application use a hard coded table structure. How can I "ask genius" for a portion of the table space / application pipeline where my application can exist? I need the first 9 table slots - I am writing an ACL application where packets have to make it through my pipeline before they can be forwarded.

It would be useful to define orderings for applications so that the table space for the flow tables can be dynamically determined. That is, I register my application requirements with genius and ask at runtime about where I should install my flows. Can Genius do this? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest asking on the project mailing list (genius-dev).

Comment: moved question to dev list as suggested.